# What is the cheapest method to get a flight from Australia to New Zealand?

Tags: air-travel, budget, australia, new-zealand, oceania

I'm planning to be about a month in Australia and then continue my trip to New Zealand. What is the cheapest method to get a flight from Australia to New Zealand? Does it make a difference from which airport to which airport I fly?

Comment: Do you know which airport you're flying out of? Sydney and Melbourne are likely to be cheapest.

Comment: I haven't planned my route yet, so I'm pretty flexible if there is a significant difference between the airports. Is there a website where I can compare prices?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual Aussie website for comparing flight prices is [Webjet](http://www.webjet.com.au/flights/), but in my experience they don't list everything.

Also they charge a booking fee so use it to find a flight but you might get a better price on the same flight elsewhere once you have the details.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes it's a lot cheaper to access the local web sites, for example, [www.airnewzealand.co.nz](http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/) instead of [www.airnewzealand.com](http://www.airnewzealand.com/).

Answer (score 7):

[Webjet.co.nz](http://www.webjet.co.nz) and [House of Travel](http://www.hot.co.nz) in my experience show the best comparisons.

I also query on [Kayak](http://www.kayak.co.uk) to double check international rates, and then have a look at the individual websites of Qantas, Air New Zealand and JetStar.

*edit*

I've also recently built a flight search engine / deals site for Australia - [Beat That Flight](https://www.beatthatflight.com.au) - where we post deals, and the prices search feature quite often beats deals sites like webjet/kayak, especially on trans-Tasman fares to New Zealand.